# list of doubles, print a String

Tags: java, type-conversion

I have a list of values (Weather data), the people who wrote the list used the value "9999" when they did not have a value to report. I imported the text file and used the following code to take the data, and edit it:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class weatherData {

public static void main(String[] args)
        throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("PortlandWeather2011.txt"));
    processData(input);
}

public static void processData (Scanner stats){
    String head = stats.nextLine();
    String head2 = stats.nextLine();
    System.out.println(head);
    System.out.println(head2);
    while(stats.hasNextLine()){
        String dataLine = stats.nextLine();
        Scanner dataScan = new Scanner(dataLine);
        String station = null;
        String date = null;
        double prcp = 0;
        double snow = 0;
        double snwd = 0;
        double tmax = 0;
        double tmin = 0;
        while(dataScan.hasNext()){
            station = dataScan.next();
            date = dataScan.next();
            prcp = dataScan.nextInt();
            snow = dataScan.nextInt();
            snwd = dataScan.nextInt();
            tmax = dataScan.nextInt();
            tmin = dataScan.nextInt();
            System.out.printf("%17s %10s %8.1f %8.1f %8.1f %8.1f %8.1f \n", station, date(date), prcp(prcp), inch(snow), inch(snwd), temp(tmax), temp(tmin));
        }
    }

}
public static String date(String theDate){
    String dateData = theDate;
    String a = dateData.substring(4,6);
    String b = dateData.substring(6,8);
    String c = dateData.substring(0,4);
    String finalDate = a + "/" + b + "/" + c;
    return finalDate;

}

public static double prcp(double thePrcp){
    double a = (thePrcp * 0.1) / 25.4;
    return a;
}

public static double inch(double theInch){
    double a = theInch / 25.4;
    if(theInch == 9999){
        a = 9999;
    }
    return a;
}


public static double temp(double theTemp){
    double a = ((0.10 * theTemp) * 9/5 + 32);
    return a;
}
}
```

The problem I am having is taking the values and checking for all times "9999" comes up, and printing out "----". I don't know how to take in a value of type double, and print out a String.

This code takes the values and checks for the value 9999, and does nothing with it. This is where my problem is:

```
public static double inch(double theInch){
    double a = theInch / 25.4;
    if(theInch == 9999){
        a = "----";
    }
    return a;
}
```

I'm sorry if I put to much information into this question. If you need me to clarify just ask. Thanks for any help!

Comment: @user962206 um... hopefully you know what's wrong in the last code snippet. If you don't... well... ... ...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to modify your `inch` function to return a string, not a double.

```
public static String inch(double theInch){
    if(theInch == 9999){
        return "----";
    }
    return Double.toString(theInch/25.4);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I forgot about type casting. :) Great answer!

Answer (score 2):

I think the first problem might be that you're reading all the values from the `Scanner` as `int` instead of `double`s. For example, based on your `System.out.println()` statement, I think you should actually be reading the following data types...

```
        prcp = dataScan.nextDouble();
        snow = dataScan.nextDouble();
        snwd = dataScan.nextDouble();
        tmax = dataScan.nextDouble();
        tmin = dataScan.nextDouble();
```

Also, seeing as though the `inch()` method is only going to be used in the `System.out.println()` line, you'll need to change it to a `String` as the return type...

```
public String inch(double theInch){
    if (theInch == 9999){
        return "----";
    }
    return ""+(theInch/25.4);
}
```